# merging the time stamps of file if label is the same

Tags: java, python, algorithm, groovy

I have file with three columns, the Ist and 2nd column are the start and end of time while the 3rd is label. I want to merge the time stamps of consecutive rows ( 2 or more) if the label in the 3rd column is the same.

## inputs1:

`0.000000        0.551875        x
0.551875        0.586875        x
0.586875        0.676188        t
0.676188        0.721875        t
0.721875        0.821250        t
0.821250        0.872063        p
0.872063        0.968625        q
0.968625        1.112250        q`

## inputs2:

`0.000000        0.551875        x
0.551875        0.586875        x
0.586875        0.676188        t
0.676188        0.721875        t
0.721875        0.821250        t
0.821250        0.872063        p
0.872063        0.968625        q
0.968625        1.112250        q
1.112250        1.212250        x
1.212250        1.500000        x`

## inputs3:

`0.000000        0.551875        x
0.551875        0.586875        x
0.586875        0.676188        t
0.676188        0.721875        t
0.721875        0.821250        t
0.821250        0.872063        oo
0.872063        0.968625        q
0.968625        1.112250        q
1.112250        1.212250        x
1.212250        1.500000        x`

## output

`0.000000        0.586875        x
0.586875        0.821250        t
0.821250        0.872063        p
0.872063        1.112250        q
1.112250        1.500000        x`

Answer (score 0):

In Groovy, given:

```
def inputs = [
    [0.000000, 0.551875, 'x'],
    [0.551875, 0.586875, 'x'],
    [0.586875, 0.676188, 't'],
    [0.676188, 0.721875, 't'],
    [0.721875, 0.821250, 't'],
    [0.821250, 0.872063, 'p'],
    [0.872063, 0.968625, 'q'],
    [0.968625, 1.112250, 'q']
]
```

Just group them by the 3rd element in each list, and then for each group create a list containing;

- the first item of the first list
- the second item of the last list
- the key that they were grouped by

Giving:

```
def outputs = inputs.groupBy { it[2] }.collect { key, items ->
    [items[0][0], items[-1][1], key]
}
```

Which results in:

```
[[0.000000, 0.586875, 'x'],
 [0.586875, 0.821250, 't'],
 [0.821250, 0.872063, 'p'],
 [0.872063, 1.112250, 'q']]
```

### Gaps

If your inputs can have gaps which you want to maintain, then you could try

```
def inputs = [[0.000000, 0.551875, 'x'],
              [0.551875, 0.586875, 'x'], 
              [0.586875, 0.676188, 't'], 
              [0.676188, 0.721875, 't'], 
              [0.721875, 0.821250, 't'], 
              [0.821250, 0.872063, 'p'], 
              [0.872063, 0.968625, 'q'], 
              [0.968625, 1.112250, 'q'], 
              [1.112250, 1.551875, 'x'], 
              [1.551875, 2.000000, 'x']]

def outputs = inputs.inject([]) { accum, line ->
    if(accum && accum[-1][2] == line[2]) {
        accum[-1][1] = line[1]
    }
    else {
        accum << line
    }
    accum
}
```

To give

```
[[0.000000, 0.586875, 'x'],
 [0.586875, 0.821250, 't'],
 [0.821250, 0.872063, 'p'],
 [0.872063, 1.112250, 'q'],
 [1.112250, 2.000000, 'x']]
```

### Wildcards

```
def inputs = [[0.000000, 0.551875, 'x'],
              [0.551875, 0.586875, 'x'], 
              [0.586875, 0.676188, 't'], 
              [0.676188, 0.721875, 't'], 
              [0.721875, 0.821250, 't'], 
              [0.821250, 0.872063, 'oo'], 
              [0.872063, 0.968625, 'q'], 
              [0.968625, 1.112250, 'q'], 
              [1.112250, 1.551875, 'x'], 
              [1.551875, 2.000000, 'x']]

def coalesce(List inputs, String... wildcards) {
    inputs.inject([]) { accum, line ->
        if(accum && 
           (accum[-1][2] == line[2] || wildcards.contains(line[2]))) {
            accum[-1][1] = line[1]
        }
        else {
            accum << line
        }
        accum
    }
}
```

then;

```
def outputs = coalesce(inputs, 'oo')
```

gives:

```
[[0.000000, 0.586875, 'x'],
 [0.586875, 0.872063, 't'],
 [0.872063, 1.112250, 'q'],
 [1.112250, 2.000000, 'x']]
```

And

```
def outputs = coalesce(inputs, 'oo', 'q')
```

Gives

```
[[0.000000, 0.586875, 'x'],
 [0.586875, 1.112250, 't'],
 [1.112250, 2.000000, 'x']]
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but I think I have more variability in data. The label can be repeated with single row or consecutive rows.

`
def inputs = [
    [0.000000, 0.551875, 'x'],
    [0.551875, 0.586875, 'x'],
    [0.586875, 0.676188, 't'],
    [0.676188, 0.721875, 't'],
    [0.721875, 0.821250, 't'],
    [0.821250, 0.872063, 'p'],
    [0.872063, 0.968625, 'q'],
    [0.968625, 1.112250, 'q'],
    [1.112250, 1.551875, 'x'],
    [1.551875, 2.000000, 'x']
]
`

Comment: @KKK Ahhhh... one sec...  So you don't want `x` rows with a `y` in the middle gap to group into a single row?  They should remain two separate `x` groups?

Comment: See inputs2: format. I added other rows to the bottom.

Comment: @KKK Can you try that second solution?  Is that more what you meant?

Comment: The output is not as desired, as you group by the labels, so it merges every occurrence of the label and the time durations. 

I only want the merge if they are consecutive and through out the file.

Comment: Could you improve it for input3, in which  I want to get rid of a specific label and add its duration (time) to the  label before it. 
In the input3 it will be lable "oo". thanks

Comment: @KKK added to the bottom...  turning in to a bit of an epic now, no?  You just testing me? ;-P

Comment: Thanks a lot. "you just tesing me?" 
Yes, and you pass :)